# Handling shared state among a lot of elements in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular.js, dynamic-programming, state

I am working on a project in Angular where I have a number of similar data objects. When you click on anyone of them it's state and amount of data shown will change. All of the objects start in the minimal state, when you click on one it becomes medium. From a medium you can click on the button to go to maximum or click anywhere else on it to go back down. There can only be one medium or maximum at a time. If there is one medium there can be no maximum, and vice versa.

[image]
[image]

Since all of the objects are by default min, I don't track that. I use a string to track which element is in an expanded state. Then I compare that objects key and the string in an ng-if to change its what is being shown. The size is managed by a conditional class, and CSS.

I chose ng-if, because there maybe a lot of elements loaded in the beginning, but there can only be one med/max at a time. I would rather load the med/max when the user wants it, instead of loading all of the med/max at that start and use ng-show for state view.

Is there a cleaner way to handle state change among many related objects? Does Angular have something to deal with this?

```js
angular.module('SizeAndState', [])
.factory('Data', function() {
        return {
            query: function() {
                return {
                    a:{ name: 'A', date: '1/2/03', number: 1},
                    b:{ name: 'B', date: '4/5/06', number: 2},
                    c:{ name: 'C', date: '8/9/10', number: 3},
                    d:{ name: 'D', date: '3/2/01', number: 4},
                    e:{ name: 'E', date: '1/2/14', number: 5},
                }
            }
        };
    })
    .controller('SizeAndStateController', ['$scope', 'Data', function($scope, Data) {
        $scope.toMin = function (clickEvent){
            clickEvent.stopPropagation();
            $scope.medElement = '';
            $scope.maxElement = '';

        };
        $scope.toMed = function (elementName, clickEvent){
            if($scope.maxElement=='') {
               if($scope.medElement == elementName){
                   $scope.toMin(clickEvent);
               } else {
                   $scope.medElement = elementName;
               }
            }
        };
        $scope.toMax = function (clickEvent){
            clickEvent.stopPropagation();
            $scope.maxElement = $scope.medElement;
            $scope.medElement = '';

        };
        $scope.data = Data.query();
        $scope.medElement = '';
        $scope.maxElement = '';
    }]);
```

```css
.campaign{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff685b;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.campaign.med{
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
}
.campaign.max{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="SizeAndState">
<div ng-controller="SizeAndStateController">
    <div class="campaign"
         ng-repeat = "element in data"
         ng-class="{'med':medElement==element.name, 'max':maxElement==element.name}"
         ng-click="toMed(element.name, $event)">
      
        <span>{{element.name}}</span> <span ng-if='medElement!=element.name && maxElement!=element.name'>Min</span>
  <span ng-if='medElement==element.name'>
   <span>Med</span>
   <h5>{{element.date}}</h5>
            <button class="btn"
                    ng-click="toMax($event)">
     to Max
            </button>
        </span>
       
       <span ng-if='maxElement==element.name'>
   <span>Max</span> 
   <h5>{{element.date}}</h5>
   <h5 ng-if='maxElement==element.name'>{{element.number}}</h5>
           <button
                ng-if="maxElement == element.name"
                ng-click="toMin($event)">
             to Min
         </button>
        </span>      
      
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) it gives you way to track model changes, so if you attach model to you elements you could track changes of elements states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd handle the state in pretty much different way.
First of all, I'd change the format of data to be an array of objects with unique ids.
So instead of

```
{
  a: { name: 'A', date: '1/2/03', number: 1},
  b: { name: 'B', date: '4/5/06', number: 2},
}
```

I'd prefer something like below, using state enums as suggested by @Ami.

```
[{ 
  id: 0, 
  name: 'Category 1',
  items: [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'A1',
    state: state.MIN
  },{
    id: 1,
    name: 'B1',
    state: state.MIN
  },...
```

With unique ids you can easily and reliably track and modify your objects.

To me, your template's logic (or "flow") is quite hard to follow. So next I would try to reduce the clutter as much as possible.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h3>Size & state</h3>

    <div ng-repeat="collection in data">
        <h4 ng-bind="collection.name"></h4>
        <span ng-repeat="item in collection.items">
            <button ng-bind="item.name"
                    ng-class="{ med: item.state, max: item.state == 2 }"
                    ng-click="changeState(collection, item)">
            </button>
          </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Where CSS

```
.med {
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
}

.max {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}
```

With these modifications, in controller, `changeState(collection, item)` function could handle all min/med/max related logic.

```
switch(item.state) {
  case state.MIN:
    _.each(collection.items, function(current) {
      current.id == item.id ? current.state = state.MED : current.state = state.MIN;
    });
    break;
  case state.MED:
    item.state = state.MAX;
    break;
  default:
    item.state = state.MIN;
}
```

If selected item's state is MIN, then change it to MED and all other items in given collection will be reset to MIN. If item's state is MED, then just change it to MAX and so on.

Notice the use of `_.each()`, which is a [underscore.js library](http://underscorejs.org/) function. It's a great lib when you need to handle arrays or collections. You didn't want to traverse the collection every time user makes a selection but I don't see it as a performance problem or anything and with uderscore, you can do it pretty much (or very close to) a single-liner.

Here's [a related plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WrmMEC).

[image]

Comment: Interesting, but what happens when it's 40 boxes instead of 4? Wouldn't that _.each start to become a problem?

Comment: Think all stuff you run on your browser. YouTube, flash games, maybe data intensive business apps. I don't think few simple objects becomes a problem. Edit my plunker and copy/paste a few hundred to begin with.

Comment: Actually I forked it for you. Here you have 3x1000 buttons running on plunker, using angular & underscore. On my not-really-highend-machine I see no problems at all http://plnkr.co/edit/gGA7tI Hope it helps.

Comment: While at it, here's a fork doing what you wanted, not iterating but changing only current/prev clicked items http://plnkr.co/edit/H4bRqS

Answer (score 4):

Your View looks fine (HTML and CSS). However, representing the state of your data elements with two string variables that may or may not be storing the "name" field on the parent data object is a very bad way of representing state.

The guiding principal for these design questions: **your object model should make it impossible to ever represent an inconsistent or meaningless state.** With your object model there are many ways to represent inconsistent and meaningless states, for example:

1. It's possible for a data item to be simultaneously in state *Med*
   and state *Max*
2. If medElement and maxElement variables contain
   values which are not equal to the name field on the parent object,
   those values are ignored

As a result your controller code is needlessly complex and very difficult to read.

**Solution:**

Represent the state of your data objects with an enum called `ElementSize` that can take exactly one of three possible state values: `minimum`, `medium`, and `maximum`. Then, use the `ng-switch` directive to specify what html you want to render for each of the three possible states.

Comment: The issue with that would be that I would need an ElementSize for every box, and there could be a lot of them. Since only one element can be medium or maximum at a time, I would have to go through the list to check for an existing med/max each time I wanted to change the size.

Comment: @EasilyBaffled The ng-switch could evaluate a function which could keep track of the state.

Answer (score 1):

@Mikko has a great solution. I tried to add this as a comment to his answer, but it was uggo.

I would change his min block to:

```
 case state.MIN:
    _.each(collection.items, function(item) {
      item.state = state.MIN;
    });
    selectedItem.state = state.MED;
    break;
```

Note: I changed the method parameter to `selectedItem` and the iteration variable to `item`. It makes more sense to me, but isn't necessary.

This change saves the comparison for every iteration which speeds it up ever so slightly.